# Hackerrank SQL problem to solve in Oracle's SQL version

Tags: sql, oracle

Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
The STATION table is described as follows:

**Sample Input**

[image]

For example, CITY has four entries: `DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY.`

**Sample Output**

```
ABC  3
PQRS 4
```

Explanation

When ordered alphabetically, the CITY names are listed as ABC, DEF, PQRS, and WXY, with lengths  and . The longest name is PQRS, but there are  options for shortest named city. Choose ABC, because it comes first alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of analytic functions; sample data in lines #1 - 6; query begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with station (city) as
  2    (select 'DEF'  from dual union all
  3     select 'ABC'  from dual union all
  4     select 'PQRS' from dual union all
  5     select 'WXY'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select city, len
  8  from (select city,
  9               length(city) len,
 10               rank() over (partition by length(city) order by city) rn
 11         from station
 12        )
 13  where rn = 1
 14  order by city;

CITY        LEN
---- ----------
ABC           3
PQRS          4

SQL>
```

---

Reading your comment, it seems you want something like this:

```
SQL> with station (city) as
  2   (select 'DEF'   from dual union all
  3    select 'ABC'   from dual union all
  4    select 'PQRS'  from dual union all
  5    select 'WXY'   from dual union all
  6    select 'XX'    from dual union all
  7    select 'ABCDE' from dual
  8   )
  9  select city, len
 10  from (select city,
 11               length(city) len,
 12               rank() over (order by length(city)     , city) rna,
 13               rank() over (order by length(city) desc, city) rnd
 14        from station
 15       )
 16  where rna = 1
 17     or rnd = 1
 18  order by len, city;

CITY         LEN
----- ----------
XX             2
ABCDE          5

SQL>
```

Comment: It's a nice piece of code, but it works if you have only the example records with length 3 and 4... if you have more records with different character lengths, it will give us their respective rank 1...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. If you could edit the question, posted more relevant sample data and desired output, I'll have a look. Also, I edited the answer, posting another query which *might* be what you want.

Comment: Yes, the second version does the trick... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question this way:

```sql
select min(tt.city), tt.city_length
  from (select s.city, length(s.city) city_length
          from station s
         where length(s.city) = (select max(length(t.city)) from station t)
            or length(s.city) = (select min(length(p.city)) from station p)
         order by 2, 1) tt
 group by tt.city_length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement with the fetch first row only clause:

```
with station (city) as
(select 'DEF'  from dual union all
 select 'ABC'  from dual union all
 select 'PQRS' from dual union all
 select 'WXY'  from dual)
 
(select city,
       length(city)
  from station
 order by 2, 1
 fetch first row only)
 
union

(select city,
       length(city)
  from station
 order by 2 desc, 1
 fetch first row only);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function in the `ORDER BY` clause and then `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT city,
       LENGTH(city) AS length
FROM   station
ORDER BY
       LEAST(
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) ASC, city ),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) DESC, city )
       )
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE station ( city ) AS
SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PQRS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CITY | LENGTH
> :--- | -----:
> PQRS |      4
> ABC  |      3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3518dabe63ca9d4a0a94430be74b7dba)*

Answer (score 0):

select min(city) || '  ' ||length(min(city)) from station

UNION

select max(city) || '  ' ||length(max(city)) from station;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely useful, especially when other answers already exist. Why should users read your answer? How is it better than what is already here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(city), len
   FROM ( 
       SELECT City, LENGTH(city) len,
       MAX(LENGTH(city)) OVER() maxlen,
       MIN(LENGTH(city)) OVER() minlen
       FROM station
        ) AS LongShort
WHERE len IN(minlen, maxlen)
GROUP BY len;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

**My Query:**

```
WITH TEMP AS 
    (SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)  AS LC
    FROM STATION) ,
    TEMP2 AS 
    (
    SELECT CITY , LC , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LC DESC , CITY ASC ) AS H ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LC ASC, CITY ASC) AS L
    FROM TEMP
    )
    
    SELECT
    CITY , LC
    FROM TEMP2
    WHERE H = 1 OR L  = 1
```

Comment: Please add a description of the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Try for [answer] and consider taking the [tour] please.